# Magnific Popup Gallery adding download button

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I have the following problem: client want's to have the possibility to download the image from gallery by clicking download button.
So is there a way to add download button inside gallery popup. Yes, the button must be inside popup, right after the user clicked thumbnail.
The code looks somehow like that.

```
<div class="gallery">
<a href="images/gallery-img-01.jpg"><img src="images/gallery-img-01.jpg"/></a>
<a href="images/gallery-img-02.jpg"><img src="images/gallery-img-02.jpg"/></a>
<a href="images/gallery-img-03.jpg"><img src="images/gallery-img-03.jpg"/></a>
<a href="images/gallery-img-04.jpg"><img src="images/gallery-img-04.jpg"/></a>
```

Comment: Look into [Photoswipe](http://photoswipe.com/) by the same author. Has what you need.

Comment: Unfortunatelly we are already using MagnificPopup in our project and it will be a waste to use a specifically new plugin just for this very one case.
Same goes to rewriting all popups with this new plugin.

Comment: Have you got solution to put Download button on Magnific Popup?

Answer (score 1):

You could change from an image type to an inline type, then adjust the mark-up from there.  Something like this ([here it is in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s65870cx/)):

```
$(".gallery a").click(function(e) {
  var file = $(this).attr("href");
  $.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
      src: $('<img src="' + file + '"/><a class="download" href="' + file + '">Download me</a>'),
      type: 'inline'
    },
    closeBtnInside: false,
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```